# How to fit automation (System or E2E) tests in agile development lifecycle?

Tags: automation, agile

I am an automation test engineer and never found a right answer on how to fit System Integration tests (E2E) in the agile development life cycle.

We are a team of 10 developers and 2 QAs. The team is currently trying to baseline a process around the best processes around verification & validation of user stories once they have been implemented.

The current process we are following is a mixture of both static reviews and manual / Automated tests.

This is how our process goes:
1. Whenever a story is ready, the lead conducts a story preparation meeting where we discuss the requirements, ensures everybody is on the same page, estimation etc;
2. The story comes onto the board and picked up by a developer 
3. The story is implemented by the developer. The implementation includes necessary unit and integration tests as well.
4. The story will then go for a code review 
5. Once the code review is passed, it will be deployed & released into production
6. If something goes wrong in production, the code will be reverted back.

The real problem with validation & verification by QA comes when there is no way to test the changes manually (as there are a lot of micro-services involved). The automation test framework is still not quite mature enough for us to write the automation tests quick enough before the developers implements their code. 
In such situations, we are compromising on quality and releasing the code without properly testing it.

What would be the best approach in this situation? Currently, we are adding all these automation tests to our QA backlog and slowly creating our regression test pack.

Any good suggestions around this process are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

> The real problem with validation & verification by QA comes when there is no way to test the changes manually (as there are a lot of micro-services involved).

This is where you need to invest time and effort. Some possible approaches include:

- Creating mock micro-services
- Creating a test environment which runs versions of the micro-services

Both of these approaches will be challenging, but when solved will typically pay-off in the medium to long term.

> Currently, we are adding all these automation tests to our QA backlog and slowly creating our regression test pack.

The value from automated regression tests comes when they have reasonable levels of coverage (say 50-70% of important features are covered). You may want to consider spending some time getting the coverage up before working on new requirements. This short-term hit on the team's output will be more than offset by:

- Savings in time spent manually testing
- More frequent running of tests (possibly using continuous integration) which improves quality
- A greater confidence amongst the developers to make changes to the code and to refactor

> The automation test framework is still not quite mature enough for us to write the automation tests quick enough before the developers implements their code.

Why not get the developers involved in writing automation tests? This would allow you to balance the creating of tests with the coding of new requirements. This may give the *appearance* of reducing the output of the team, but the team will become increasingly efficient as the coverage improves.

> We are a team of 10 developers and 2 QAs

I like to think you are a team of 12 with development and QA skills. Share knowledge and spread the workload until you have a team that can deliver requirements *and* quality.

Answer (score 0):

For our team, we lose time, but after a development story is done the corresponding test auomation story is put in to the next sprint.

Finished stories are unit tested and run through the current test automation scripts to make sure we haven't regressed with our past tests/code.

Once the new tests are constructed, we run our completed code via HP UFT and if successful, setup for deployment to Production.

This probably isn't the best way to get things done currently, but it has been a way for us to make sure everything gets automated and tested before heading to Production.